# Replicate NA cell locations in one data frame in another

Tags: r, matrix

I have two entities: matrix and dataframe. Matrix has numbers in all cells. The second data frame has NA in a few cells. How can I ensure that the first matrix has NA in the same exact position as in the latter data frame.

I tried complete.case() and na.omit but this unfortunately removes row all together. I tried a for loop where it iterates by column then by row, checks where the cell is zero and returns location which would then feed into the indp dataframe - get a few errors around dimensions:

Running through my logic. This iterates one column at a time then row; where the cell contains a 0, then take the same cell location in the indp matrix and set to 0 - but nothing seems to be happening.

```
numZero <- 0 
cols <- 0    
for (i in 1:ncol(ws)){
  for (k in 1:nrow(ws)){
    if (is.na(ws[k,i])){
      print(indp[i,k])
      indp[i,k] <- 0  
      numZero <- numZero + 1
    }

  }
  cols <- cols +1
}
```

It should be noted that the indp is a matrix.

Added the cols and numzero to keep a tab on number of rows and cols because I keep getting the following error: 
Error in indp[i, k] : subscript out of bounds. The indp and ws have the same dimensions. However, the col and numzero counters return cols and rows that are different to the dimensions. Also nothing is happening to the indp matrix. Am I missing something?

Also attaching pictures of the two to help conceptualise: 
[indp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLh4W.png)

Note the 0's:
[ws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dTb6.png)

Looking to do the following: 
Original matrix:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Data frame:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  5  1  0 NA
2  3  3  1  2  2
3  0  1  5  4 NA
4  5 NA  3  2  0
5 NA  0  3  4  1
```

I would like the first matrix to be come as per the above - have NAs exactly in the same cells:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   NA
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   NA
[4,]    4   NA   14   19   24
[5,]   NA   10   15   20   25
```

Further to this,

```
m1 <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5);set.seed(25); 
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5), 5*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
numZero <- 0 
cols <- 0    
for (i in 1:ncol(dat1)){
  for (k in 1:nrow(dat1)){
    if (is.na(dat1[k,i])){
      print(dat1[i,k])
      m1[i,k] <- 0  
      numZero <- numZero + 1
    }
    else{
      print(dat1[i,k])
    }

  }
  cols <- cols +1
}
```

Printing the cell entries at each iteration to compare against the original data entities but I am getting different figures to what's in them which is odd as I thought m1[1,1], e.g. should return the cell entry.

Comment: You can do `m1[is.na(dat1)] <- NA`

Comment: Not sure I follow akrun? How is this accounting for both entities?

Comment: As I understand the question `m1 <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5);set.seed(25);
 dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5), 5*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))`  The code above replace the values in `m1` to NA for corresponding `NA` values in 'dat1'

Comment: Your question is `How can I ensure that the first matrix has NA in the same exact position as in the latter data frame.`

Comment: And yes that's the question, thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided any reproducible example.  WIth the example I constructed, it is working fine.

Comment: I just ran your example and m1 becomes ` [1]  5  9 21 23` after running 'm1[is.na(dat1)]`. What I'm looking to achieve is the following. Get m1 to have NA exactly where dat1 has NAs, e.g.                                            `[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]`
`[1,]    1    6   11   16   NA`
`[2,]    2    7   12   17   22`
`[3,]    3    8   13   18   NA`
`[4,]    4   NA   14   19   24`
`[5,]   NA   10   15   20   25 `

Comment: akruns code works perfectly fine and it keeps the original matrix structure, what on earth are you talking about? I'm voting to close this until you make your question clear.

Comment: Bear with me - what more info would you like? I believe my question is quite clear, I also gave an example of the structure. Akrun's outputs the following:  5 9 21 23. I am not sure how this respects the structure of the original entities.

Comment: Using this forum to learn so apologies if I'm not as advanced.  I would appreciate your help & patience.

Comment: Please provide `dput` for both the matrix and the data frame using something like `dput(m1)` and `dput(df1)` respectively.

Comment: I edited the question. I see that Akrun's code returns the numbers which should be NA in m1, whereas I am looking to edit m1 such that those returned numbers 5 9 21 23  show NA in m1. Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Are you kidding me? `m1[is.na(dat1)] <- NA` does exactly that. Check `m1` after you run this line. Also, if you want to ping someone, you need to use @ before his name, otherwise he won't see it.

Comment: Missed Akrun's '<-NA' - genius. Many thanks @Akrun and for your patience. Thanks for the tip David, newbie to the forum.

Comment: @David can you please upvote my entry as a token of your hospitality to the forum? ^^

Comment: @akrun you could probably post that as I can't find a dupe currently.

Answer (score 0):

We can get a logical matrix with `is.na(dat1)`, extract the elements in 'm1' that corresponds to TRUE values from the logical matrix and assign it to `NA`

```
m1[is.na(dat1)] <- NA
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    6   11   16   NA
#[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
#[3,]    3    8   13   18   NA
#[4,]    4   NA   14   19   24
#[5,]   NA   10   15   20   25
```